# Scan picture and detect lines

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection

I've got an assignment as follow: "Using cvFilter2D function with the suitable kernels in order to scan a picture and then only hold lines that are +- 45 degree and +- 60 degree".

Can someone give me some clues, especially how to calculate the kernels?

Comment: You need "Learning OpenCV" This is covered in chapter 6.

Answer (score 1):

You need a little bit of precalculus.
I assume you want to create a line kernel. So you need to know how to create a line.

http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/archive/archive-f2000/mp/mp4/anti.html holds plenty of techniques.

In the end, sum over all pixels in the kernel, and normalize them so they add up to 1.

Comment: thank you! but what you mean "normalize them so they add up to 1" ?

Comment: Well you have a kernel of some size, for example a 5x5 kernel, filled with 1's and 0's (in the case of no antialiasing). If you add up all the numbers in the kernel, they may add up to 13 for example. This shouldn't be allowed to happen because after applying the kernel to the image, the brightness will increase 13fold. So when you make your kernel, you make sure to get the total sum of the pixels in the kernel and divide each pixel by that number, so the kernel will be normalized.

Comment: thanks! ^~^ ! it seem that if the line is thick enough, the result for that line will include 2 edge lines ! i've read some web pages,they said that we must make a "skeletonization" before applying Kernels ! could you give me a clue how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my late response ! i've done this assignment ! First, thank you again, Perfanoff ! thanks to your reference link, i've found out the way to solve problem !
Here is my code:

```
// Image Transforms.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

/*The purpose of this program is to detect lines which are +-45 degree and +- 60 degree from a binary picture.*/
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include "cv.h"
 #include "highgui.h" 

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
//IplImage* src = cvLoadImage("C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\black white 1.jpg");
IplImage* src = cvLoadImage("C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\line detection 4.png");

cvNamedWindow("src", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
cvShowImage("src", src);    

IplImage* DstSum = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src),src->depth, 3);
IplImage* Dst45 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src),src->depth, 3);
IplImage* Dst135 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src),src->depth, 3);
IplImage* Dst60 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src),src->depth, 3);
IplImage* Dst120 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src),src->depth, 3);

/*double Ker0 [] = { -0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                -0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1
                };
double Ker90 [] = {-0.1,0,0.2,0,-0.1,
                -0.1,0,0.2,0,-0.1,
                -0.1,0,0.2,0,-0.1,
                -0.1,0,0.2,0,-0.1,
                -0.1,0,0.2,0,-0.1
                }; */

double Ker45[]={
                 0,-0.1,-0.1, 0, 0.2,
                -0.1,-0.1, 0, 0.2, 0,
                -0.1, 0, 0.2, 0,-0.1,
                 0, 0.2, 0,-0.1,-0.1,
                0.2, 0,-0.1,-0.1, 0
                };// 45 degree 

CvMat Kernel45=cvMat(5, 5, CV_64FC1,Ker45);

double Ker135[]={
        0.2, 0,-0.1,-0.1, 0,
        0, 0.2, 0,-0.1,-0.1,
        -0.1, 0, 0.2, 0,-0.1,
        -0.1,-0.1, 0, 0.2, 0,
        0,-0.1,-0.1, 0, 0.2
        };// 135 degree 

CvMat Kernel135=cvMat(5, 5, CV_64FC1,Ker135);

double Ker120[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                  1/7,0.25/7,0,0,0,0,0,
                  0,0.75/7,0.75/7,0.25/7,0,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0.75/7,0.6/7,0.25/7,0,
                  0,0,0,0,0.4/7,0.75/7,1/7,
                  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0,0,0,0
                };//120 degree
CvMat Kernel120=cvMat(7, 7, CV_64FC1,Ker120);

double Ker60[] = {0,0,0,0,1/7,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0.25/7,0.75/7,0,0,
                  0,0,0,0.6/7,0.4/7,0,0,
                  0,0,0.25/7,0.75/7,0,0,0,
                  0,0,0.75/7,0.25/7,0,0,0,
                  0,0.25/7,0.75/7,0,0,0,0,
                  0,1/7,0,0,0,0,0
                };//60 degree

CvMat Kernel60=cvMat(7, 7, CV_64FC1,Ker60);

cvFilter2D(src,Dst60,&Kernel60,cvPoint(-1,-1));
cvThreshold(Dst60,Dst60,100,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);

cvFilter2D(src,Dst120,&Kernel120,cvPoint(-1,-1));
cvThreshold(Dst120,Dst120,100,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);

cvFilter2D(src,Dst45,&Kernel45,cvPoint(-1,-1));
cvThreshold(Dst45,Dst45,200,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);

cvFilter2D(src,Dst135,&Kernel135,cvPoint(-1,-1));
cvThreshold(Dst135,Dst135,200,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);

cvAdd(Dst45,Dst60,DstSum,NULL);
cvAdd(Dst135,DstSum,DstSum,NULL);
cvAdd(Dst120,DstSum,DstSum,NULL);

cvNamedWindow("dst", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
cvShowImage("dst", DstSum);

cvReleaseImage(&DstSum);

cvWaitKey(0);

cvReleaseImage(&src);

cvDestroyWindow("src");
cvDestroyWindow("dst"); 

return 0;
```

}

Here is the result:
[image]